# Private Docker Registry backed by Docker Hub when image not found

Tags: docker, private, docker-registry

This seems extremely simple and obvious but I can't seem to think of how to phrase my search properly as it only seems to turn up the basic setup.

I have a Private Docker Registry which is empty.  I want to pull something that is Public (Alpine Linux).  I pull from my Private Registry, it responds with not found.

Is there a configuration that allows a follow-on check against public Docker Hub which will then pull and return that image instead of giving up?  Something possibly similar to Artifactory?

Comment: Do you mean you want your docker-compose file to fallback to a public registry if your private one returns nothing?

Comment: No.  There's a particular behavior in Artifactory where I can pull for a file from an on-prem installation.  If this particular image is not found locally it will check something public (like Docker Hub).

It will then cache that particular image making it available internally.  

I would expect a docker-compose file to operate the way you said by using this single repository in that manner.  (Hopefully makes sense, please ask for any clarifications)

Comment: I should mention I am using the OSS Harbor Private Registry to get this behavior although with minimal configuration, I'm just not seeing it.  I see replication and other registry endpoints, but they aren't appearing to give the behavior I'm looking to gain.